# jsconfig and jest not interacting to use same root paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am building a react project and currently having issues having jest use jsconfig for using the root path when doing tests.

the structure is like this,

```
├── divjoy-project.json
├── jsconfig.json
├── next.config.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
├── README.md
├── src
├── tailwind.config.js
├── worker
└── yarn.lock
```

jsconfig is simply,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

and jest is

```
 "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/?(*.)(spec|test).?(m)js?(x)"
    ],
    "rootDir":"./src",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "mjs"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.m?jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 80,
        "functions": 80,
        "lines": 80,
        "statements": -10
      }
    }
  },
```

I'm using next.js as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `"moduleDirectories": ['node_modules', '<rootDir>']` in your jest config. That is so jest finds your jsconfig file.

In my case, I have a jest.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>'],
  // other configs
}
```

I'm also using next.js and the above worked for me.